# Executing a Powershell script in CMD.EXE from a location with "Illegal characters in path"

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am attempting to call a Powershell script in cmd.exe and the script is in a location that looks like this: c:Data\foo - bar\location-1\ShellScript.ps1

When I am calling this script I have tried using single and double quotes around the path with no luck.

```
PowerShell.exe -File "c:\Data\foo - bar\location-1\ShellScript.ps1" Arg1 Arg2
```

From what I have read I assumed that the above would work but this did not work nor did single quotes.

I appreciate any ideas.

Thanks
*Edit * Mistype on my example path. Sorry.

Comment: At a minimum, you will need to put in the missing \ so: c:\Data\foo - bar\location-1\ShellScript.ps1

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a mistype in posting.  The path I am working with in my code is correct.

Comment: It is possible that it is something in the script itself. Do the same path with a test script that just does an Out-Host or something.

Comment: When I change the location of the script to somewhere that does not have " " (Space) or "-" in the file path I can call the script with no issues. This was how I determined that this wqas my issue.

Comment: What if you call it like this: cmd /c Powershell.exe blah

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.  Move the file location?

Comment: Do this in your cmd prompt: cmd /c Powershell.exe "c:\Data\foo - bar\location-1\ShellScript.ps1" Arg1 Arg2

Comment: I figured it out.  This article was a huge help. added "&'C:\Data\foo -bar\location-1\Shellscript.ps1'"
http://poshoholic.com/2007/09/27/invoking-a-powershell-script-from-cmdexe-or-start-run/

Answer (score 12):

One solution is to move to PowerShell v3 where this works fine:

```
PS> powershell.exe -file 'C:\temp\foo - bar\location-1\foo.ps1' arg1 arg2
made it!, args are arg1, arg2
```

If you need to stay on V2 try escaping the spaces e.g.:

```
PS> powershell.exe -file "C:\temp\foo` -` bar\location-1\foo.ps1" arg1 arg2
```

From cmd.exe, this should work:

```
C:\> PowerShell.exe -Command "& {& 'c:\Data\foo - bar\location-1\ShellScript.ps1' Arg1 Arg2}"
```

Comment: That is from the Powershell "shell" the question was about executing powershell scripts directly from cmd

Answer (score 3):

```
PowerShell.exe -File "c:\Data\foo - bar\location-1\ShellScript.ps1"
```

should be escaped

```
PowerShell.exe "& ""c:\Data\foo - bar\location-1\ShellScript.ps1"""
```

yep that really is a total of 6 double quotes