# Running a Powershell script from c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script from C# code, but I'm having some (maybe environmental) issues:

On a machine where I try to run it, the following occur:

1. PowerShell starts and loads as Admin
2. PowerShell window immediately closes (apparently) without error

#### Notes:

- The script works. When I run it from ISE, it runs without errors.
- If I right click the script and choose Run with PowerShell, I get a Execution Policy error even though I don't change it in the script.

---

> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a
>    policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution
>   policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please 
>   see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
>   At line:1 char:46
>   + if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process  ...
>   +                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

- Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

  ```
       Scope                ExecutionPolicy
       -----                ---------------
   MachinePolicy              Unrestricted
      UserPolicy                 Undefined
         Process                    Bypass
     CurrentUser              Unrestricted
    LocalMachine              Unrestricted
  ```
- I believe that this is environmental because:

  - It ran fine a few days ago
  - It runs fine on other computers

#### This is the code I use to invoke the script:

```
if (File.Exists("Start.ps1"))
{
    string strCmdText = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Start.ps1");

    var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe ", strCmdText);
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

The script itself is irrelevant, as I have changed it to a simple

```
Write-Host "Hello"
$d=Read-Host
```

and I have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried this switches `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted` ?

Comment: @AramKocharyan He has machine policy set, won't do.

Comment: Changed the GP to Unrestricted to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hmm. How about changing the script to a `Copy-Item` call so you can trace if it actually does something? Sadly, cannot test the C# code, although I can emulate it in Powershell. EDIT: emulated and in case of my PC, Powershell->Powershell did work with a test script, that is, it waited for `Read-Host` to provide data.

Comment: Please post exact code on how do you set execution policy, and whether it's a C# or Powershell code, and how it's called. Probably you might just ignore the error, especially if you're setting the policy to a more restrictive one.

Comment: @Vesper I don't set the policy in the code. Ever. I have a pre-requirement that the Policy is set to (atleast) remote signed. Both the c# and powershell code is at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was in the path of the script. It had spaces on this particular machine and I had not handled that.

The window closed too fast to see any error but setting

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

helped me catch it.

The execution policy had nothing to do with my error.

To fix it I changed the path in the c# code like explained here: [Executing a Powershell script in CMD.EXE from a location with "Illegal characters in path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469236/executing-a-powershell-script-in-cmd-exe-from-a-location-with-illegal-character)

Complete code:

```
if (File.Exists("Start.ps1"))
            {
                File.GetAttributes("Start.ps1");
                string strCmdText =   Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Start.ps1");
                var process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"&'"+strCmdText+"'\"";

                process.Start();
                string s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();

                using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("StandardOutput.txt", true))
                {
                    outfile.Write(s);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first: An **alternative**, more efficient and flexible way to execute PowerShell code from a .NET executable is to use the ***PowerShell SDK***, which **enables *in-process execution* with *full .NET type support*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648785/45375) for an example.

---

While [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30846513/45375) provides an effective solution, there is a *simpler* one that also works with script-file paths that happen to contain `'` characters:

In order **to execute a `.ps1` file via [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, use its `-File` paramete**r, which then only requires you to enclose the script file path in embedded `"..."` if you use `.Arguments` (.NET Framework) / pass the script file path as-is to `.ArgumentList.Add()` (.NET (Core)), and allows you to specify any pass-through arguments as literals (with embedded double-quoting), if needed:

```cs
# ... 
string strCmdText = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Start.ps1");
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
# ...
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
// Use '-File' with embedded "..." quoting.
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-File \"{0}\"", strCmdText);
// In a .NET Core / .NET 5+ application you can alternatively use:
//   process.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add("-File");
//   process.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add(strCmdText);
# ...
```

Note:

- If `-File` isn't specified, `powershell.exe` assumes `-Command` as the target parameter, which, after stripping (unescaped) `"` from all subsequent arguments, *then* subjects them to interpretation *as PowerShell code* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458726/45375) for background information.
- For a comprehensive overview of the PowerShell CLI, in both PowerShell editions, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136129/45375).

Answer (score -1):

As you list the policies, apparently there is a group policy implemented against your computer (even if it's not in the domain, there's still local GP in effect) that changes `MachinePolicy` which is above all the locally set policies to "RemoteSigned", which is more strong policy than "Unrestricted" in terms of code execution. If your PC is in a domain, you can run "Resultant set of policy (Logging)" as local administrator and get the domain policy that affects your PC. If not, run Local Security Policy from Control Panel/Administrative Tools and navigate "Computer configuration - Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Windows PowerShell" and check the value of policies there ("Enable scenario execution" - roughly translated from localized), and if needed, you can change the value in there. After you do, reload Powershell.

Comment: I set the Machine policy hoping that it will fix the issue. That is how I noticed that running the script by rightclicking it does a hidden bypass. Setting it to Unrestricted does not fix it.