# Passing argument from C# to called PowerShell Script

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-sdk

I have the following function in my C# file:

```
private void RunScriptFile(string scriptPath, string computerName, PSCredential credential)
{
   RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
   Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
   runspace.Open();
   RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
   Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
   string scriptCommand = "Invoke-Command -ComputerName " + computerName + " -FilePath " + scriptPath + " -ArgumentList " +  credential;
   pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptCommand);
   Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
   runspace.Close();
}
```

I am calling the following PowerShell script using Credentials passed in the above C# code;
script.ps1

```
Param([PSCredential]$Credentials)
<code part using credentials>
```

After `pipeline.Invoke()`, C# code just gets closed without any action, no errors are thrown too.

Is there something I am doing wrong while making the call?
The same call if invoked from PowerShell like below works fine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <computerName> -FilePath <scipt.ps1> -ArgumentList " +  credential;
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be calling `.AddScript(x)` and not just `.Add(x)`?

Comment: @LarryTang I think so because I have tried running this using `.AddScript(x)` without the Credential argument and it worked, I will have to check what does `.Add(x)` do though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you use [`.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.commandcollection.addscript) with a *self-contained*  command**, you **must embed arguments in *string* form**, as part of the PowerShell code snippet you're passing - and that won't work for a `PSCredential` instance.

In order **to pass arguments *as specific .NET types* in the context of a *single command***, you can instead use a [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell) instance with the  [`.AddCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addcommand) and [`AddParameter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameter) / [`AddArgument()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addargument) methods.

Applied to your scenario:

```
private void RunScriptFile(string scriptPath, string computerName, PSCredential credential) {
  Collection<PSObject> results; 
  using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
    ps.AddCommand("Invoke-Command")
      .AddParameter("ComputerName", computerName)
      .AddParameter("FilePath", scriptPath)
      .AddParameter("ArgumentList", new object[] { credential })
    results = ps.Invoke();
  }
}
```

This approach has the added advantage of not requiring any parsing of PowerShell code, which is faster and more robust.

In general, use of the `PowerShell` class simplifies use of the PowerShell SDK and is sufficient in many cases (often there is no need to manage runspaces, pipelines, ... explicitly).

---

However, as [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) points out, **[`PowerShell.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript#System_Management_Automation_PowerShell_AddScript_System_String_) *can* accept typed arguments**, if you **reformulate the code snippet to *declare (typed) parameters***, via a `param(...)` block and then call `.AddParameter()` / `.AddArgument()`:

```
ps.AddScript(@"param([string] $ComputerName, [string] $FilePath, [pscredential] $Credential) Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilePath $FilePath -ArgumentList $Credential")
  .AddArgument(computerName)
  .AddArgument(scriptPath)
  .AddArgument(credential)
```

As you can see, however, that makes the solution more verbose.

Declaring parameters makes the intent more obvious, but you can **alternatively use the automatic, array-valued `$args` variable to access the arguments passed *positionally***:

```
ps.AddScript(@"Invoke-Command -ComputerName $args[0] -FilePath $args[1] -ArgumentList $args[2]")
  .AddArgument(computerName)
  .AddArgument(scriptPath)
  .AddArgument(credential)
```

---

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/45375) for guidance on **what NuGet package to use** in your C# application, depending on the host application and/or target PowerShell edition.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69051991/45375) for how to **handle errors** in the context of using the PowerShell SDK.