# How to automate either PowerShell or PowerShell Core for same machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

With the release of PowerShell Core, how can an application choose which version of Powershell (Powershell 5.x or PowerShell Core) is being called when it using hosting automation library (system.management.automation)? Something about the runspace that should be created? or maybe the connection info?

Comment: windows powershell = `powershell.exe` ///// powershell 6+ = `pwsh.exe` [*grin*]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an overview of the **PowerShell SDK-related NuGet packages**:<sup>Adapted from [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8625#issuecomment-456515037).</sup>

Note: <del>`System.Management.Automation`</del> is *not* recommended for direct use.

- To **create *stand-alone applications*** that **host the PowerShell runtime** in order to call PowerShell commands in-process:

  - Use [`Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies/) for **.NET Framework** (*Windows-only*) applications using the legacy **Windows PowerShell** runtime.
  - Use [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/) for (potentially cross-platform) **.NET Core / 5+**. applications using the [**PowerShell (Core) v6+**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)  runtime.

    - To determine what specific .NET (Core) runtime a given package version must be combined with at a minimum, select the package version of interest on the linked page, expand the `Dependencies` section, and consult the first entry; e.g., for package version `7.2.0` the minimum required .NET (Core) runtime is `net6.0`.
- To **create assemblies that implement *cmdlets* / form part of modules for use *in PowerShell*** or to create a *PowerShell host*:

  - Use [`PowerShellStandard.Library`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library/); it is **compatible with *both* Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) v6+**, but [**note**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellStandard):

    - "[This] reference assembly **contains no actual implementation** but rather will allow you to use only APIs that exist across different versions of PowerShell. This means that **you still need to run within a PowerShell runtime.**"

---

**As for targeting a specific edition / version via *remoting*:**

- See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58238481/45375)
- Note that it covers remoting from the perspective of using PowerShell *cmdlets*, not the SDK, though you can always call the cmdlets via the SDK as well.

---

As [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) points out in a comment on the question, the edition-specific **executable filenames** are:

- `powershell.exe` - **Windows PowerShell**
- `pwsh.exe` (Windows) / `pwsh` (Unix-like platforms) - **PowerShell (Core) v6+**