# Could not load assembly 'System.Management.Automation

Tags: c#, powershell, import, .net-assembly, powershell-cmdlet

I developed a custom Powershell CmdLet.

```
namespace GetStuff
{
    using System.Management.Automation;

    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Stuff")]
    [OutputType(typeof(Stuff[]))]
    public class GetStuffCmdLet : PSCmdlet
    {

    }
}
```

after Building the project i tried to import it in PowerShell
with `Import-Module .\GetStuff.dll -Force`
The following Error Message appeared:

> Import-Module : **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation**, >Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> At line:1 char:1
> Import-Module .\GetStuff.dll -Force
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: Looks like you compiled your module against version 7.2.1 of the library. If you want to write cmdlets for Windows PowerShell (5.1 and earlier), you need to compile against the "Windows PowerShell Reference Assemblies" instead of `S.M.A.dll` - if both = PowerShell Standard

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/45375) provides an overview of the various PowerShell SDK NuGet packages and when to use which.