# Hosting Powershell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I need help.

I want to run a PowerShell script from C#. I added `System.Management.Automation` from Nuget packages...

But I this error

[image]

I tried in a console app and a Windows app.

Comment: You want the Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK package.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen installed it in my project

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen but still have that error

Comment: Which version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i am new in C# 

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen .Net FrameWork 4.7.2

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/45375) provides an overview of the various PowerShell SDK NuGet packages and when to use which. Do _not_ use the `System.Management.Automation` package directly.