# Cloud not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation' while running powershell script

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure, powershell

So I am trying to run some powershell script on my WPF app to update my IpRules on Azure but even simple script like "Write-Output 'Hello, World!'" gives me this error:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=7.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=token123456'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Here is my code:

```
        public Collection<PSObject> GetExistingFirewallIPRules(string script, Dictionary<string, object> scriptParameters)
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript(script);
            return ps.Invoke();
        }
```

And here is .csproj

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
      <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.AppService" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Core" Version="8.1.97" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Wpf" Version="8.1.97" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.2.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

How can I fix this error or is it any other way to update my CosmosDB IpRules in Azure portal than running powershell (eg. "Update-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $accountName -IpRangeFilter $ipFilter") script?

Comment: You may have an issue with version.  Try opening with Visual Studio.  If you get same error from solution explorer delete reference than add back reference which will give latest version.  VS should automatically update version when open but will fail if it cannot find library.

Comment: I am still getting this same error but there is one more thing. I cannot install latest package because I am getting this "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package System.Management.Automation 7.3.1 is not compatible with net6.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package System.Management.Automation 7.3.1 supports: net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0) Dover.DXM.DevTool.Modules.SqlConfiguration C:\Users\...." 1

Comment: You need to get the Nuget Library that is compatible with core : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/?force_isolation=true

Comment: I changed System.Management.Automation library version to  7.2.8 and it seems to be working. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `System.Management.Automation` NuGet package *directly* is *not* recommended - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/45375) for what package to choose for what scenario.

In the context of a **.NET (Core)** application, **use *only* the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/) package** (similarly, *all* flavors of the PowerShell SDK only require *one* package).

- That you mistakenly used *both* and had *conflicting version numbers* is likely what caused your problem.

Since you're targeting .NET *6*, you must use an *older* version of that package, given that the version that is current as of this writing, `7.3.1` requires .NET *7*; for .NET 6, use a `7.2.x` version

In other words:

- Remove line `<PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.2.8" />`
- Update line `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.3.1" />` to 
  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.2.8" />`