# ORACLE ManagedDataAccess Core in PowerShell 7

Tags: .net, oracle, powershell, .net-core, powershell-sdk

I have a simple .NET 7 class library referencing this NuGet package (NO other ORACLE packages are included):

```
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.100" />
```

Then I have a PowerShell module written in C# (also targeting .NET 7). It references the above mentioned project.

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
```

The PowerShell module has only one cmdlet, `Test-Oracle`. It invokes a method from the Core.dll. The method attempts to connect to ORACLE and execute `SELECT * FROM dual`.

Works perfectly on my machines - it connects to ORACLE and outputs data. My client, running the same code, gets this exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral......
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot that?

---

**EDIT:**

The "core" project, that does the actual querying to ORACLE, references these NuGet packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.100" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="serilog.sinks.console" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="serilog.sinks.file" Version="5.0.0" />
```

The PowerShell module project includes this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.0-preview-06">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
   </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55734), a possible explanation is that your client may have built the project targeting .NET Framework rather than .NET (Core).

Comment: @mklement0 the client does not build the code, I do. They just load the final dll of the module using `Import-Module` . In the real app there is module manifest and everything, I just narrowed the app to the part where we have the problem.

Comment: I see. Per the linked issue, the implication of your symptom is that "the assembly is referencing WindowsImpersonationContext that was intentionally omitted in .NET Core", so are there other assemblies involved that aren't .NET (Core)? I assume you're targeting the .NET (Core) version of the PowerShell SDK. Does the PowerShell module  do something on initialization that - situationally - could cause a .NET Framework assembly to be loaded?

Comment: I'll update my question with list of NuGet packages I'm referencing.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that you're using `PowerShellStandard.Library` implies that your PowerShell module (cmdlet) can also run in _Windows PowerShell_, not just in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). Is your client perhaps running the module in Windows PowerShell, whereas you're using it in PowerShell (Core)? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/45375) for which PowerShell SDK NuGet packages are used for what environment.

Comment: No, our intention is to support only PowerShell 7. What should I use instead of `PowerShellStandard.Library`? (I got that one from `dotnet new` template most likely)

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**:

- The answer below does *not* solve the problem, but may be of interest for authoring PowerShell modules that should enforce use in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *only*, i.e. should refuse to load in *Windows PowerShell*.
- To further narrow down your problem, I suggest implementing an [assembly-resolve event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads) and logging the results:

  - It is invoked when the runtime itself fails to locate an assembly whose loading is being requested.
  - The [`ResolveEventArgs.RequestingAssembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resolveeventargs.requestingassembly) property of the event-arguments object contains the assembly that *requested* the load.

---

I may not have the complete picture, but my understanding is this:

You're using the [`PowerShellStandard.Library` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library), which implies that your PowerShell module (cmdlet) *can also run in Windows PowerShell*, not just in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).

- *Conceivably*, the problem arose from your client running the module in *Windows PowerShell*, causing an attempt to reference the no-long-present-in .NET (Core) `System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext` type - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55734) for background.

However, in order to create a PowerShell module that can be used in a *regular PowerShell session* (as opposed to creating an application that *itself hosts PowerShell*), you *must* use the `PowerShellStandard.Library` package - but there is *no* built-in way that I know of to then *constrain the module to only run in one edition or the other* (providing better targeting in the future is the subject of [GitHub issue #5541](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5541)).

Thus, **if you want to enforce that your module can be used in PowerShell (Core) only**, you'll have to implement that yourself:<sup>[1]</sup>

- Binary PowerShell modules support an initialization hook that is called when the module is loaded (imported).
- In that hook, you can test whether you're running inside .NET Framework (which implies *Windows PowerShell*) or .NET (Core) (which implies *PowerShell (Core)*). If the former, you can throw an exception.

Here's a proof-of-concept, using ad hoc-compiled C# code for simplicitly:

```
Add-Type @'
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace YourNamespace {
  // Initialization hook.
  public class MyModuleAssemblyInitializer : IModuleAssemblyInitializer
  {
      public void OnImport()
      {
          // Test if the runtime is .NET Framework, which implies Windows PowerShell,
          // and throw an exception if so.
          if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription.StartsWith(".NET Framework ")) 
          {
            throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException("This module supports PowerShell (Core) only; it cannot run in Windows PowerShell.");
          }
      }
  }
  
  // Sample cmdlet.
  [Cmdlet("Get", "Foo")]
  public class GetFooCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
    protected override void ProcessRecord() {
      WriteObject("Hi from Get-Foo");
    }
  }

}
'@ -PassThru | ForEach-Object Assembly | Import-Module
```

- If you execute the above in a PowerShell (Core) session, the import should succeed, and you should be able to call `Get-Foo` thereafter.
- If you execute in a *Windows PowerShell* session, a `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception should be thrown.

---

<sup>[1] Note: Even though PowerShell [module manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests) have a [`CompatiblePSEditions` entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_module_manifests#compatiblepseditions) in order to declare edition compatibility, it seems to have purely *informational* character and *isn't enforced*, up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.3.7 (the current version as of this writing). Currently, the entry is respected *solely* when attempting to import *Windows PowerShell*'s *system modules*, i.e. those stored in `$env:windir\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`, in *PowerShell (Core)*.</sup>

Comment: Hi @mklemement0, thanks for answer. I'm absolutely positive they are running it in PowerShell 7. I don't need to enforce that, it is a given prerequisite and they accept it. I saw the code failing on their machine, and it WAS run in PS 7. My problem is, even though they use PowerShell 7, the module fails to open a connection to ORACLE, with the above mentioned error.

Comment: Understood, @Petr. Please see the preface I've added to the answer, with respect to using an assembly-resolve event handler to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid it has nothing to do with PowerShell 5. I tried and it is not even possible to install/import the module. I'm troubleshooting this module: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CAT/ It works, but on one of our client's machine it refuses to connect to ORACLE with the above mentioned error.