# How to add Arguments to powershellinstance in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, powershell

I have a powershell script i need to execute it using c#

```
string psData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\m\Desktop\power.ps1");
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(psData);

            IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke();
            while (!result.IsCompleted)
            {
                Logger.Info("Wait initiated");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            Logger.Info("Execution completed");
        }
```

Using above code script is executing but how can i pass arguments to shell script

I have changed code

```
string psData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\m\Desktop\power.ps1");
        Process pr = new Process();
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \""+psData+"\" \"arg1\" \"arg2\"",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        pr.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        pr.Start();
        pr.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `AddArgument` or `AddParameter` methods described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0)?

Comment: @fedrik can i pass all my arguments as a string in one .AddArgument()? it seems for all arguments i need to add them separately

Comment: If it is not in the documentation, no.

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646703/passing-argument-from-c-sharp-to-called-powershell-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AddArgument Method. 
More Info -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addargument?view=pscore-6.2.0 
**-------- Old Answer-----------------**
Not Sure about How to do it via PowerShellInstance class, But you can use Process class for invoking PowerShell script with argument.

```
var file = @"C:\<Directory>\GetServices.ps1";
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "powershell.exe",
    Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted \"{ps1File}\"",
    UseShellExecute = false
};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

For more info -> https://duanenewman.net/blog/post/running-powershell-scripts-from-csharp/

 **Edit 2**

```
  string psData = @"C:\Users\manis\Desktop\test.ps1";
    Process pr = new Process();
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file {psData} hello",
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    pr.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    pr.Start();
    pr.WaitForExit();
```

And my Powershell script looks like this

```
param ($param1)
write-host $param1
```

Comment: how can i pass arguments using this method

Comment: same as you run in PowerShell, example command -param1 value, in this case, it will be like -Param1 value1 - Param2 value2 in argument property, all will be in string @Iceberg

Comment: `Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted \"{ps1File}\" arg1 arg2",` this is not working

Comment: In this example, -NoProfile and ExecutionPolicy is argument, you can remove those, and add your argument, make sure that your script is running correctly in power shell

Comment: `powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file "C:\Users\m\Desktop\power.ps1" "arg1" "arg2"` this code works in cmd. But when i pass same code in arguments inside c# it is not working

Comment: i tried this but not working 
`$servername=$args[0]
$envname=$args[1]
New-Item -Path "C:\$servername $envname.txt" -ItemType File `
I used this script file and after executing code file name with passed arguments are not created

Comment: $servername=$args[0] 
$envname=$args[1] 
New-Item -Path $servername -Name "$envname.txt" -ItemType File

Comment: I modified it a bit

Comment: var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = @$"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file {psData} C:\ hello",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212776/discussion-between-iceberg-and-manish).