# Using a powershell object in C# to retrieve cmdlet get-physicaldisk

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

Problem with Powershell  object in C#9

I am trying to retrieve physical disks in C# using a system.management.powershell object.
When I try using the cmdlet “Get-Process” the powershell object retrieves all processes correctly.

```
  using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // this works
        //PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Get-Process");
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-PhysicalDisk");
        //PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Out-String -Width 240 -Stream");
        Collection<PSObject> outlist = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
    }
```

When I try using the cmdlet “Get-PhysicalDevice” no data is returned, and no errors are thrown.

---

I have also tried using a Runspace and a pipeline to execute get-process, and all processes are returned correctly.

```
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();
Pipeline p = rs.CreatePipeline();
p.Commands.Add("get-process");
// p.Commands.Add("get-physicaldisk");
Collection<PSObject> results = p.Invoke();
rs.Close();
```

When I try get-physicaldisk with a runspace the program throws a command not found exception.
I am transferring a server monitor from VB to C#.  The Runspace (get-physicaldisk) works correctly in VB using  .net framework 4.1.7.

I am using System Management 5.0, ..Automation 7.1.4, and Powershell SDK 7.1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your execution policy to `RemoteSigned` so that the Storage module can be imported

```
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.InitialSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned;
    runspace.Open();
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create(runspace))
    {
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-PhysicalDisk");
        Collection<PSObject> outlist = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; I was trying to explain in general terms how to diagnose the problem, but the specific cause of a module failing to import hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: Btw, do you know what inside that module necessitates enabling scripts to run (as an aside: `Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned` should suffice and is probably preferable)? In a pristine PowerShell session, it works for me even with policy `Restricted`, but in conjunction with loading _unrelated_ format data in my `$PROFILE` file I do see the symptom.

Comment: @mklement0, Unfortunately I do not.  I just happened to notice the error that the module wasn't loading.  I have tested with `RemoteSigned` and it also works for me so I have updated my answer.  I have not been able to get it to work with `Restricted`

Answer (score 4):

[Daniel's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69052040/45375) provides an effective solution for the case at hand.

This answer explains **how the PowerShell SDK reports errors and how to inspect them**:

- The [`.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddScript) PowerShell SDK method is for passing one more PowerShell *statements*  for execution; that is, you can pass a snippet of *PowerShell source code*, as you would find in a `.ps1` script *file*.
- By contrast, the [`.AddCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddCommand) method accepts the *name* or *executable path* of a single PowerShell command - without arguments; the latter must be added with separate calls, namely via a single `.AddParameters()` call, or via argument-individual `.AddParameter()` and `.AddArgument()` calls.

Choosing one method over the other has implications with respect to *error handling*, specifically with respect to *statement-terminating* errors, such as when calling a *nonexistent command* or, as it turned out to be the case for you, a command whose module failed to import:

- `.AddScript()`-added code does *not* throw a .NET exception when `.Invoke()` is called and a statement-terminating error occurs - instead, an *empty collection* is returned, the `.HadErrors` property returns `true`, and the error(s) that occurred can be examined via the `.Streams.Error` collection.
- `.AddCommand()`-added code *may* throw a .NET exception, e.g. of type `System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException`.

By contrast:

- *Script*-terminating errors (those created with a `throw` statement or via `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` / `-ErrorAction Stop`) *always* create a .NET exception for the caller.

  - `throw`, as a PowerShell statement, can only be executed via `.AddScript()`, but setting `$ErrorActionPreference` / using `-ErrorAction` is also possible in connection with `.AddCommand()`.
- *Non*-terminating errors (e.g., `Get-ChildItem nosuchfile`) *never* create a .NET exception for the caller.

See also:

- [Non-terminating vs. terminating errors, and the latter's sub-types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375)
- [A comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583)