# .NET Plugin infrastructure and PowerShell in .NET 5: Fails to invoke Get-Disk cmdlet

Tags: .net, powershell, plugins, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 that uses the **plugin capability, as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support)**.

I've created a plugin that uses PowerShell (Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK nuget package (v7.1.4)).

Inside the plugin, I'm executing this code:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript("Get-Disk");
    ps.Invoke();    
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ps.Streams.Error));
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

> The 'Get-Disk' command was found in the module 'Storage', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Storage'.

So, I tried executing

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript("Import-Module Storage; Get-Disk");
    ps.Invoke();    
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ps.Streams.Error));
}
```

And this is what I get:

> One or more errors occurred. (The getter method should be public, not void, static, and have one parameter of the type PSObject.);The 'Get-Disk' command was found in the module 'Storage', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Storage'.

What am I doing wrong? This code works perfectly if I invoke the code outside the loaded plugin.

## EDIT

I've created a minimal reproducible example of the problem, [you can see it here](https://github.com/SuperJMN-Tutorials/PowerShellViaPlugin). The code is super simple. Be sure to compile every project before running it. Otherwise, the plugin won't be compiled and won't load from the main app.

Comment: That's curious, and it's a curious error. I tried with a pristine project (same versions), and it seems to work fine. I'm only half-joking: have you tried cleaning up the build artifacts and rebuilding from scratch?

Comment: @mklement0 OMG, I think it's related to the environment I was running. I ran it using LINQPad (using .NET 5, of course). I've created a console application from scratch and it worked, surprisingly. I had issues in the application I was migrating, too. I'll double check it tomorrow and come with more info.

Comment: In some cases you may also need to set the execution policy to at least RemoteSigned in order to load the Storage module.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69052040/11954025) for an example of one way to do this

Comment: I've updated the OP because it seems to be related to the plugin mechanism of .NET 3.1+. I've uploaded a minimal reproducible example. Please, take a look. Thanks!

Comment: .NET Core 3.0+, to be exact