# How to catch a Powershell terminating exception in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, exception, .net-4.0

How can I catch the Powershell exceptions `AccessDeniedException` and `GroupExistsException` within my C# program for the cmdlet `New-LocalGroup`

```
        try
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddCommand("New-LocalGroup");
            ps.AddParameter("Name", groupName);
            ps.AddParameter("Description", description);

            ps.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is ?)

            throw ex;
        }
```

So far, I have this link from Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord.Exception?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the [`New-LocalGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localgroup) cmdlet emits are *non-terminating* PowerShell errors (unless you use *invalid syntax*), which do *not* translate into .NET exceptions.

Instead, they are written to PowerShell's *error output stream*, which you can examine via [`ps.Streams.Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatastreams.error#System_Management_Automation_PSDataStreams_Error)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69051991/45375) for more information.

Comment: I really wanna learn c# :(. How did you find out if the cmdlet was a non-terminating error? Is there a simple way?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, generally speaking, _most_ cmdlet errors are non-terminating. You can easily provoke a _terminating_ one with a _syntax error_, by passing a non-existent parameter name. If you're unsure in a given situation, use the following trick (using a `Get-Item` call as an example): `'!' + (Get-Item nosuch)`: If `!` still prints, the error is non-terminating.