# Emulate Powershell in C# - Enter-PSession does not work

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to emulate a powershell/powershell-ISE console with a winform. Using Powershell.Create()/Invoke(), I can do pretty much everything to replicate the behaviour, but I'm missing something regarding the change of runspace when entering a remote session. Consider the code below:

```
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();          
            ps.AddScript("$i = 1").Invoke();
            ps.AddScript("Enter-PSSession -computer localhost").Invoke();
            var obj = ps.AddScript("$i").Invoke();
            // obj contains 1, whereas I would expect not to find $i
```

I'm wondering how I could make it transparent for the user that typing enter-pssession would actually change the runspace, just like powershell.exe would do.

Answer (score 2):

**[`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession)** isn't supported in the context of the PowerShell SDK.

In fact, it isn't even supported in regular scripting or via the CLI; it **only works when invoked from an *interactive* PowerShell session** - see [GitHub issue #16350](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16350).

You'll see the problem:

- if you run your program from an *elevated* session ("loopback" remoting to the same machine requires that)
- if you examine the errors that occurred, via `ps.Streams.Error`:

  - When you use `.AddScript()`, any errors that occur during execution of the PowerShell code do *not* surface *as exceptions* in your C# program; instead, you must examine the `.Streams.Error` collection (`.HadErrors` is a Boolean that indicates whether any errors occurred) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69051991/45375) for details.

You'll see the following error, which may be related to the PowerShell host that the SDK uses, `Default Host`, missing features required by `Enter-PSSession`:

> Enter-PSSession : The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.
Is  there any way I can achieve what I'm trying to achieve ? any other way ?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped, @UtilitaireCCV; my pleasure. If you want to allow users to type arbitrary commands, including `Enter-PSSession`, you'd have to intercept `Enter-PSSession` calls and handle entering a remote runspace yourself, which sounds challenging.