# Why does PowerShell split arguments at spaces when invoked by a batch script and how to fix it?

Tags: powershell

Very simple setup, please do try this at home.

#### test.ps1

```
$args
```

#### test.rb (replace with language of choice, if necessary)

```rb
p ARGV
```

#### test.bat

```
@echo off
ruby test.rb "foo bar moo"
powershell .\test.ps1 "foo bar moo"
pause
```

Run *test.bat*. Guess the output.

If you think like me, you're wrong.

#### Output

```
["foo bar moo"]
foo
bar
moo
```

Ruby is my witness that the three words are passed as single argument. What in Bill Gates' name is PowerShell doing? And how can I make it work logically?

Or what am I missing?

Comment: Okay, I found a workaround at least: `powershell .\test.ps1 """foo bar moo"""`. So it requires escaped quotes? But why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to **invoke a *script file* (`.ps1`) with arguments**, use the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)'s **`-File`** (`-f`) parameter, not the (implied) `-Command` (`-c`) parameter:

```bash
powershell -File .\test.ps1 "foo bar moo"
```

Note that [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (`pwsh`, PowerShell versions starting with v6) now *defaults* to `-File`.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

```bash
powershell .\test.ps1 "foo bar moo"
```

is implicitly the same as (you can also use `-c` instead of `-Command`):

```bash
powershell -Command .\test.ps1 "foo bar moo"
```

and that causes PowerShell to evaluate the arguments in two stages:

- First, syntactic `"` around individual arguments are *stripped* and the resulting arguments are then joined with spaces to form a single string.
- Second, the resulting string - `.\test.ps1 foo bar moo` in this case - is then interpreted *as PowerShell source code*, and, as you can see, the original `"` have been stripped by then, resulting in the script receiving *3* arguments.

  - Note that the same applies in cases where the *script path* has embedded spaces and must therefore be quoted:

    ```bash
    :: !! BROKEN, because PowerShell *removes the double quotes and 
    :: !! ultimately executes: & C:\path with spaces\script.ps1         
    powershell -Command ^& "C:\path with spaces\script.ps1"
    ```
- `-Command`'s behavior therefore also involves subjecting the arguments to additional interpretation according to *PowerShell*'s rules, unlike with `-File`. E.g.,
  `powershell -File .\test.ps1 $HOME` would pass `$HOME` *verbatim* to the script, whereas
  `powershell -Command .\test.ps1 $HOME` would pass *the value of PowerShell's automatic `$HOME` variable*.
- With `-Command`, passing `"` characters that are to become part of the resulting PowerShell code being evaluated indeed requires *escaping*:

  - From PowerShell's perspective, the most robust form is `\"` (sic), though that can result in broken command lines when calling from batch files / `cmd.exe`
  - In cases where that's a problem, pass a single argument enclosed in `"..."` to `-Command`, and escape pass-through `"` as `""` in PowerShell (Core) / as `"^""` (sic) in Windows PowerShell.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for more guidance on when to use `-File` vs. `-Command`.

---

<sup>[1] It is understandable to expect `-File`, not `-Command` to be the *default* parameter, given that most shell and script-engine CLIs require an *explicit* parameter (typically, `-c` or `-e`) to pass a *command string* rather than a script-file path. Fortunately, in PowerShell (Core) 7+ `-File` now *is* the default, a change that was necessary to support shebang lines on Unix.

Additionally, most shell and script-engine CLIs expect the command string to be passed as a *single* argument, with any additional arguments then becoming arguments *passed to the code in the command string*, whereas PowerShell simply stitches multiple arguments together and then interprets the result as the command string; see [GitHub issue #4024](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4024#issuecomment-311541803)</sup>

Comment: TL;DR: RTFM. Thanks for explaining this. I somehow was convinced that just passing the file and arguments were the way to go. Probably because it coincidentally worked in the past.

Comment: @Neonit, yes, situationally it can work. And it's understandable to expect `-File` to be the default, not `-Command`, given that most CLIs require an explicit parameter to pass a command string, such as `-c` or `-e`. Fortunately, in PowerShell (Core) 7+ `-File` now _is_ the default (this was necessary to support shebang lines on Unix). I've also included this information as a footnote to the answer, and I've added a link to an answer that provides further guidance on `-File` cs. `-Command`.