# How do I call the PowerShell CLI robustly, with respect to character encoding, input and output streams, quoting and escaping?

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, command-line-interface, io-redirection, quoting

This self-answered question aims to give a **systematic overview of the PowerShell CLI (command-line interface)**, both for *Windows PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`) and [*PowerShell (Core) v6+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (`pwsh.exe` on Windows, `pwsh` on Unix).

While official help topics exist (see the links in the answer), they do not paint the full picture and lack systematic treatment (as of this writing).

Among others, the following questions are answered:

- How do the edition-specific CLIs differ?
- How do I pass PowerShell code to be executed to the CLIs? How do `-Command` (`-c`) and `-File` (`-f`) differ?
- How do the arguments passed to these parameters need to be quoted and escaped?
- What character-encoding issues come into play?
- How do the PowerShell CLIs handle stdin input, and what stdout / stderr do they produce, and in what format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### PowerShell CLI fundamentals:

- **PowerShell editions**: The CLI of the legacy, bundled-with-Windows ***Windows PowerShell*** edition is **[`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**, whereas that of the cross-platform, install-on-demand **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** edition is **[`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh)** (just **`pwsh`** on Unix-like platforms).
- **Interactive use**:

  - By default, unless code to execute is specified (via `-Command` (`-c`) or `-File` (`-f`, see below), an interactive session is entered. However, unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, **you can use `-NoExit` to still enter an interactive session *after* executing code**. This is especially handy for troubleshooting command lines when the CLI is called without a preexisting console window.
  - Use **`-NoLogo`** to suppress the startup text that is shown when entering an interactive session (not needed if code to execute is passed). [GitHub issue #15644](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15644) suggest *not* showing this startup text *by default*.
  - To **opt out of telemetry / update notifications**, define the following environment variables *before* entering an interactive session: `POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1` / `POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK=Off`
- **Parameters and defaults**:

  - All **parameter names are case-*insensitive*** (as PowerShell generally is); most parameters **have short aliases**, such as **`-h`** and **`-?`** for **`-Help`**, which shows command-line help, which with `pwsh` (but not `powershell.exe`) also lists these short aliases.

    - Caveat: For long-term stability of your code, you should either use the full parameter names or their official aliases. Note that PowerShell's "elastic syntax" also allows you to use *prefixes* of parameter names *ad hoc*, as long as such a prefix *unambiguously* identifies the target parameter; e.g., `-ver` unambiguously targets `-version` *currently*, but - at least hypothetically - such a call could break in the future if a new parameter whose name also starts with `ver` were to be introduced.
  - [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) supports *more* parameters than `powershell.exe`, such as `-WorkingDirectory` (`-wd`).
  - There are **two (mutually exclusive) ways to pass code to execute**, in which case the PowerShell process exits automatically when execution ends; pass `-NonInteractive` to prevent use of interactive commands in the code or `-NoExit` to keep the session open after execution:

    - **`-Command` (`-c`)** is for **passing *arbitrary PowerShell commands***, which may be passed either as a single string or as individual arguments, which, after removing (unescaped) double-quotes, are later joined with spaces and then interpreted as PowerShell code.
    - **`-File` (`-f`)** is for **invoking *script files* (`.ps1`)** with pass-through arguments, which are treated as *verbatim* values.
    - **These parameters must come *last* on the command line**, because all subsequent arguments are interpreted as part of the command being passed / the script-file call.
    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for guidance on when to use `-Command` vs. `-File`, and the bottom section for quoting / escaping considerations.
    - It is **advisable to use `-Command` (`-c`) or `-File` (`-f`) *explicitly***, because **the two editions have different *defaults***:

      - `powershell.exe` defaults to `-Command` (`-c`)
      - `pwsh` defaults to `-File` (`-f`), a change that was necessary for supporting shebang lines on Unix-like platforms.
    - Unfortunately, **even with `-Command` (`-c`) or `-File` (`-f`), [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) (initialization files) are *loaded by default*** (unlike POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, which only do so when starting *interactive* shells).

      - Therefore, it is **advisable to routinely precede `-Command` (`-c`) or `-File` (`-f`) with `-NoProfile` (`-nop`)**, which suppresses profile loading for the sake of both avoiding extra overhead and a more predictable execution environment (given that profiles can make changes that affect all code executed in a session).
      - [GitHub proposal #8072](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8072) discusses introducing a *separate CLI (executable)* that does *not* load profiles in combination with these parameters and could also improve other legacy behaviors that the existing executables cannot change for the sake of backward-compatibility.
- **Character encoding (applies to both in- and output streams)**:

  - Note: The **PowerShell CLIs only ever process *text***<sup>[1]</sup>, both on input and output, never raw byte data; what the CLIs output by default is the same text you would see in a PowerShell session, which for complex objects (objects with properties) means human-friendly formatting *not* designed for programmatic processing, so **to output complex objects it's better to emit them in a *structured* text-based format, such as JSON**.

    - Note what while you can use `-OutputFormat xml` (`-of xml`) to get CLIXML output, which uses XML for object serialization, this particular format is of little use *outside* of PowerShell; ditto for accepting CLIXML input via stdin (`-InputFormat xml` / `-if xml`).
  - On **Windows**, the PowerShell CLIs respect the console's code page, as reflected in the output from `chcp` and, inside PowerShell, in `[Console]::InputEncoding`. A console's code page defaults to **the system's active OEM code page**.

    - **Caveat**: OEM code pages such as [`437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems are fixed, single-byte character encodings limited to 256 characters in total. **To get full Unicode support, you must switch to code page `65001`** *before* calling a PowerShell CLI (from `cmd.exe`, call `chcp 65001`); while this works in both PowerShell editions, `powershell.exe` unfortunately switches the console to a raster font in this case, which causes many Unicode characters not to *display* properly; however, the actual data is not affected.

      - **On Windows 10, you may switch to UTF-8 *system-wide***, which sets both the OEM and the ANSI code page to `65001`; note, however, that this **has far-reaching consequences**, and that the feature is still in beta as of this writing - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).
  - On **Unix**-like platforms (`pwsh`), **UTF-8** is *invariably* used (even if the active locale (as reported by `locale`) is *not* UTF-8-based, but that is very rare these days).
- ***Input*-stream (stdin) handling** (received via *stdin*, either piped to a CLI call or provided via input redirection `<`):

  - To process stdin input **as data**:

    - Explicit use of the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) is required.
    - This in turn means that in order to pass stdin input to a *script file* (`.ps1`), `-Command` (`-c`) rather than `-File` (`-f`) must be used. Note that this makes any arguments passed to the script (symbolized with `...` below) subject to interpretation by PowerShell (whereas with `-File` they would be used verbatim):
      `-c "$Input | ./script.ps1 ..."`
  - To process stdin input **as code** (`pwsh` only, seems to be broken in `powershell.exe`):

    - While passing PowerShell code to execute via stdin works in principle (by default, which implies `-File -`, and also with `-Command -`), it **exhibits undesirable pseudo-interactive behavior and prevents passing of arguments**: see [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223); e.g.:
      `echo "Get-Date; 'hello'" | pwsh -nologo -nop`
- ***Output*-stream (stdout, stderr) handling**:

  - (Unless you use a script block (`{ ... }`), which only works from *inside* PowerShell, see below), ***all* 6 PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) are sent to *stdout*, including *errors*(!)** (the latter are normally sent to *stderr*).

    - However, when you apply an - external - stderr *redirection* you can selectively suppress error-stream output (`2>NUL` from `cmd.exe`, `2>/dev/null` on Unix) or send it to a file (`2>errs.txt`).
    - See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669365/45375) for more information.

---

#### Quoting and escaping of the `-Command` (`-c`) and `-File` (`-f`) arguments:

**When calling *from PowerShell*** (rarely needed):

- **There is rarely a need to call the PowerShell CLI *from* PowerShell**, as as any command or script can simply be called *directly* and, conversely, calling the CLI introduces overhead due to creating a child process and results in loss of type fidelity.
- If you still need to, the most robust approach is to **use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)**, which avoids all quoting headaches, because you can use PowerShell's own syntax, as usual. Note that using script blocks *only* works from inside PowerShell, and that you cannot refer to the *caller's* variables in the script block; however, you can use the `-args` parameter to pass arguments (based on the caller's variables) to the script block, e.g., `pwsh -c { "args passed: $args" } -args foo, $PID`; using script blocks has additional benefits with respect to output streams and supporting data types other than strings; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404296/45375).

  ```sh
  # From PowerShell ONLY
  PS> pwsh -nop -c { "Caller PID: $($args[0]); Callee PID: $PID" } -args $PID
  ```

**When calling from *outside* PowerShell** (the typical case):

Note:

- `-File` (`-f`) arguments *must* be passed as *individual arguments*: the script-file path, followed by arguments to pass to the script, if any. Both the script-file path and the pass-through arguments are used *verbatim* by PowerShell, after having stripping (unescaped) double quotes on Window<sup>[2]</sup>.
- `-Command` (`-c`) arguments *may* be passed as multiple arguments, but in the end PowerShell simply joins them together with spaces, after having stripped (unescaped) double quotes on Windows, before interpreting the resulting string *as PowerShell code* (as if you had submitted it in a PowerShell session).

  - **For robustness and conceptual clarity, it is best to pass the command(s) as a *single argument* to `-Command` (`-c`)**, which **on Windows requires a *double*-quoted string (`"..."`)** (although the overall `"..."` enclosure isn't strictly necessary for robustness in no-shell invocation environments such as Task Scheduler and some CI/CD and configuration-management environments, i.e. in cases where it isn't `cmd.exe` that processes the command line first).
- Again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for guidance on when to use `-File` (`-f`) vs. when to use `-Command` (`-c`).
- To *test-drive* a command line, call it from a `cmd.exe` console window, or, in order to simulate a no-shell invocation, use <kbd>WinKey-R</kbd> (the `Run` dialog) and use `-NoExit` as the first parameter in order to keep the resulting console window open.

  - Do *not* test from *inside* PowerShell, because PowerShell's own parsing rules will result in *different* interpretation of the call, notably with respect to recognizing `'...'` (single-quoting) and potential up-front expansion of `$`-prefixed tokens.

On **Unix**, *no* special considerations apply (this includes Unix-on-Windows environments such as WSL and Git Bash):

- You only need to satisfy the *calling* shell's syntax requirements. Typically, programmatic invocation of the PowerShell CLI uses the POSIX-compatible system default shell on Unix, `/bin/sh`), which means that inside `"..."` strings, *embedded* `"` must be escaped as `\"`, and `$` characters that should be passed through *to PowerShell* as `\$`; the same applies to interactive calls from POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`; e.g.:

  ```sh
  # From Bash: $$ is interpreted by Bash, (escaped) $PID by PowerShell.
  $ pwsh -nop -c " Write-Output \"Caller PID: $$; PowerShell PID: \$PID \" "

  # Use single-quoting if the command string need not include values from the caller:
  $ pwsh -nop -c ' Write-Output "PowerShell PID: $PID" '
  ```

On **Windows**, things are more complicated:

- `'...'` (single-quoting) can only be used with `-Command` (`-c`) and never has *syntactic* function on the PowerShell CLI *command line*; that is, single quotes are always preserved and interpreted as verbatim string literals when the parsed-from-the-command-line argument(s) are later interpreted as PowerShell code; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for more information.
- `"..."` (double-quoting) *does* have syntactic command-line function, and *unescaped* double quotes are *stripped*, which in the case of `-Command` (`-c`) means that they are *not* seen as part of the code that PowerShell ultimate executes. **`"` characters you want to *retain* must be *escaped*** - even if you pass your command as individual arguments rather than as part of a single string.

  - **`powershell.exe`** requires `"` to be escaped as **`\"`**<sup>[3]</sup> (sic) - even though *inside* PowerShell it is `` ` `` (backtick) that acts as the escape character; however `\"` is the most widely established convention for escaping `"` chars. on Windows *command lines*.

    - Unfortunately, from `cmd.exe` this can *break* calls, if the characters between two `\"` instances happen to contain `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` and `|`; **the robust - but cumbersome and obscure - choice is `"^""`**; `\"` will *typically* work, however.

      ```sh
      :: powershell.exe: from cmd.exe, use "^"" for full robustness (\" often, but not always works)
      powershell.exe -nop -c " Write-Output "^""Rock  &  Roll"^"" "

      :: With double nesting (note the ` (backticks) needed for PowerShell's syntax).
      powershell.exe -nop -c " Write-Output "^""The king of `"^""Rock  &  Roll`"^""."^"" "

      :: \" is OK here, because there's no & or similar char. involved.
      powershell.exe -nop -c " Write-Output \"Rock  and  Roll\" "
      ```
  - **`pwsh.exe`** accepts **`\"`** or **`""`**.

    - `""` is the robust choice when calling from `cmd.exe` (`"^""` does *not* work robustly, because it normalizes whitespace; again, `\"` will *typically*, but not always work).

      ```sh
      :: pwsh.exe: from cmd.exe, use "" for full robustness
      pwsh.exe -nop -c " Write-Output ""Rock  &  Roll"" "

      :: With double nesting (note the ` (backticks)).
      pwsh.exe -nop -c " Write-Output ""The king of `""Rock  &  Roll`""."" "

      :: \" is OK here, because there's no & or similar char. involved.
      pwsh.exe -nop -c " Write-Output \"Rock  and  Roll\" "
      ```
  - In ***no-shell* invocation scenarios**, **`\"` can safely be used in *both* editions**; e.g., from the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>); note that the first command would *break* from `cmd.exe` (`&` would be interpreted as `cmd.exe`'s statement separator, and it would attempt to execute a program named `Roll` on exiting the PowerShell session; try without `-noexit` to see the problem instantly):

    ```sh
      pwsh.exe -noexit -nop -c " Write-Output \"Rock  &  Roll\" "

      pwsh.exe -noexit -nop -c " Write-Output \"The king of `\"Rock  &  Roll`\".\" "
    ```

---

See also:

- **Quoting headaches** also apply in the *inverse* scenario: **calling external programs *from* a PowerShell session**: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).
- When calling from `cmd.exe`, **`%...%`-enclosed tokens such as `%USERNAME%`** are **interpreted as (environment) variable references** by `cmd.exe` itself, up front, both when used unquoted and inside `"..."` strings (and `cmd.exe` has no concept of `'...'` strings to begin with). While typically desired, **sometimes this needs to be prevented**, and, unfortunately, the solution depends on whether a command is being invoked *interactively* or *from a batch file* (`.cmd`, `.bat`): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375).

---

<sup>[1] This also applies to PowerShell's in-session communication with external programs.</sup>

<sup>[2] On Unix, where no process-level command lines exist, PowerShell only ever receives an array of *verbatim* arguments, which are the result of the calling shell's parsing of its command line.</sup>

<sup>[3] Use of `""` is *half broken*; try `powershell.exe -nop -c "Write-Output 'Nat ""King"" Cole'"` from `cmd.exe`.</sup>

Comment: As Powershell noob this is a goldmine, while the docs about sections are helpfull I found it lacking in allot of areas specially when calling powershell externally for automation reasons. Your article here bridges allot of gaps in my thinking. Excellent!