# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json omitting Depth > 1

Tags: powershell, convertfrom-json

Given this JSON

`{"name":"//iam.googleapis.com/projects/aw-b9a-8231-4086-a297-ca0/serviceAccounts/1081069135974252","asset_type":"iam.googleapis.com/ServiceAccount","resource":{"version":"v1","discovery_document_uri":"https://iam.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest","discovery_name":"ServiceAccount","parent":"//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/1090951556423","data":{"email":"default@aw-d1eb6b9a-8231-4086-a297-ca0.iam.gserviceaccount.com","name":"projects/aw-d1eb6b9a-8231-4086-a297-ca0/serviceAccounts/default@aw-d1eb6b9a-8231-4086-a297-ca0.iam.gserviceaccount.com","oauth2ClientId":"108102635374252","projectId":"aw-d1eb6b9a-8231-4086-a297-ca0","uniqueId":"108108526913531974252"}},"ancestors":["projects/1090951556423","folders/940897400840","folders/140924730741","organizations/437515948226"],"update_time":"2021-02-08T18:23:18Z"}`

I'm trying to use the following snippet from Windows command window,

`powershell -nologo -executionpolicy bypass "& {foreach($line in Get-Content temp.txt) {ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $line}}" > temp2.txt`

To get the retrieved keys and values into a file (temp2.txt).  However, ConvertFrom-Json only gets the first hierarchic level of the JSON, now down in the `data` array.  I have tried `-Depth 3` but get this error:

````
At line:1 char:81
+ ... ontent temp.txt) {ConvertFrom-Json  -InputObject $line -Depth 4 -Comp ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand```
````

Comment: The `-Depth` parameter is only available in PS Core (6.2 and up), not earlier versions of PowerShell. Having said that, PowerShell 5.1 on my machine decodes everything correctly without having to specify more depth. If you only need what's in `data`  you should just drill into the object: `(ConvertFrom-Json ...).resource.data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) points out in a comment, only in *PowerShell (Core) v6.2+* does [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) have a `-Depth` parameter. However, even if it were available to you, it would neither be needed nor would it help, because **`ConvertFrom-Json` correctly parses JSON with a nesting depth *up to `1024` levels* by default**.

- In other words: **`ConvertFrom-Json -Depth $someDepth` is *only* needed** in the unlikely event that **your JSON has *more* than `1024` levels** *or* if you want **to ensure that input JSON does not exceed a given nesting depth** (because exceeding it results in an *error* - unlike how `-Depth` works with the complementary cmdlet, [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375)).

---

Your problem stems from the fact that `>`, PowerShell's [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) operator is in effect an alias of [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), which, when given complex objects as input, saves them using the same *for-display* representation you would see *in the console* - and with a deeply nested input object such as yours the resulting interpretation can be unhelpful (since your input object has more than 4 top-level properties, it is implicitly formatted with [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list)).

- Note: You're actually using `cmd.exe`'s `>` operator, but the above still applies, because the same kind of formatting is also applied when PowerShell outputs to an outside caller's stdout.

So the question for you to decide is:

- What representation are you looking for to be saved in file `temp2.txt`?
- Are you looking for a *for-display* representation - for the *human observer* - or a format suitable for later *programmatic processing*?

**If you're primarily looking to *pretty-print* the input JSON**, you can use a `ConvertFrom-Json` / `ConvertTo-Json` *round-trip* operation, whose output will be pretty-printed by default:

```sh
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -c "ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content -Raw temp.txt) | ConvertTo-Json" > temp2.txt
```

Note:

- As hinted at above, with `ConvertTo-Json`, i.e. the re-conversion *to* JSON, `-Depth` (available also in Windows PowerShell) is much more likely to be required (though not with your particular input object), because the default depth is only `2`, and exceeding it results in *quiet truncation* (up to PowerShell 7.0; since v7.1, at least a *warning* is issued) - again, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).
- I've streamlined incidental aspects of your call to `powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call - for a comprehensive overview of the CLI in both PowerShell editions, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136129/45375).
- You may run into character-encoding issues with non-ASCII characters, given that `cmd.exe` uses the system's active OEM code page. Saving to a file from inside the PowerShell command can give you control over the desired encoding.

Comment: Done!  Jeroen's part of the answer helped although it wasn't quite the same question.  I struggle with Powershell as a newbie, it's good stuff but hard to put the pieces together (as opposed say Javascript which is much more intuitive at least to me).  I have a head for wierd code though, in my defense I know LOTS about XSLT for example.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Dave. Yes, PowerShell takes some getting used to, but it's worth putting in the time to understand its fundamentals, as it will make you much more productive. (Unfortunately, PowerShell's commitment to backward-compatibility has  also resulted in quite a few historical warts being part of the package).