# PowerShell: pwsh -Command/-File with string parameter containing a parameter to be passed to a subprocess with a rooted path as value

Tags: powershell

Why can't we have a `-Path C:/some/path` inside a string parameter?

**Using -Command:**

`pwsh.exe -Command .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B "-Path a/b/c"`

```
hello.ps1: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'a/b/c'.
```

`pwsh.exe -Command .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B '-Path a/b/c'`

```
hello.ps1: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'a/b/c'.
```

**Using -File:**

`pwsh.exe -File .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B "-Path a/b/c"`

```
Hello!
B: -Path a/b/c
```

Good! Now with a rooted path:

`pwsh.exe -File .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B "-Path C:/a/b/c"`

```
hello.ps1: Missing an argument for parameter 'B'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
```

Hmm.. now with a unix style path:

`pwsh.exe -File .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B "-Path /c/a/b/c"`

```
Hello!
B: -Path /c/a/b/c
```

ok... but what's wrong with the colon?

`pwsh.exe -File .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B "-Path :"`

```
hello.ps1: Missing an argument for parameter 'B'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
```

`pwsh.exe -File .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B ":"`

```
Hello!
B: :
```

So it's really when the string has `-Something` before the colon that the issue arise. Is there a way to escape that colon?

(PSVersion 7.2.0)

**[EDIT]** hello.ps1 would be a run script that spawns a subprocess (could be any executable, including pwsh.exe)

**[EDIT (based on answers)]**

Possible wordarounds:

- Quotes: `pwsh.exe -Command "./hello.ps1 -A 123 -B '-Path C:/a/b/c'"`
- Script block and quotes: `pwsh.exe -Command "& {./hello.ps1 -A 123 -B '-Path C:/a/b/c'}"`

Comment: Read and follow `pwsh.exe -?`. Use `pwsh.exe -Command "& {%CD%\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B ""-Path a/b/c""}"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call the PowerShell CLI robustly, with respect to character encoding, input and output streams, quoting and escaping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136128/how-do-i-call-the-powershell-cli-robustly-with-respect-to-character-encoding-i)

Comment: @zett42, that's an excellent post to link to :) - but we're dealing with a bona fide _bug_ here.

Comment: This works indeed and could be a workaround (using single quotes): 
`pwsh.exe -Command "& {./hello.ps1 -A 123 -B '-Path C:/a/b/c'}"`

Comment: @CandyRedTele, from _inside_ PowerShell, just use `{ ... }` - unquoted - as shown at the top of my answer. From _outside_ PowerShell, use `"./hello.ps1 -A 123 -B '-Path C:/a/b/c'"` (as shown later in my answer) - no need for `"& { ... }"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: If you're **calling *from within PowerShell*** and really want to create *another PowerShell process* (which is unusual), the best solution, which bypasses all quoting headaches, is to **pass a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)** to the (positionally implied) `-Command` paramter:

```sh
# Works robustly; if you need to include variable values from the 
# current session:
#  * append -Args ... 
#  * and refer to them via $args inside the script block.
pwsh.exe { .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B "-Path :" }
```

The following pertains to **calls to `pwsh`**, the PowerShell (Core) [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh), ***from the outside***:

---

> `pwsh.exe -Command .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B "-Path a/b/c"`

That this fails is to be expected: Using `-Command` means that *after* syntactic `"` have been stripped during command-line parsing the result is *then* interpreted as PowerShell code, which means that your call is equivalent to the following in-session call:

```sh
# !! Fails, because, after " stripping, *two* arguments are passed to `-B`
.\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B -Path a/b/c
```

The problem does *not* arise with `'...'` quoting (your 2nd command) *when called from `cmd.exe`*, because `'` has no *syntactic* function on the command line when PowerShell is called *from the outside*, and is therefore passed through.

However, the caveat is that - since `cmd.exe` doesn't (ever) recognize `'...'` quoting - any `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` would have to be `^`-escaped. You can avoid that if you enclose the *entire PowerShell command* in `"..."`, however (that would also make it work from PowerShell, but, as stated, use of script blocks is preferable there):

```sh
# OK - overall "..." quoting, which protects the value inside '...'
pwsh.exe -Command ".\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B '-Path a/b/c&d'"
```

---

By contrast, using `-File` does *not* entail parsing the command-line arguments that follow *as a piece of PowerShell code*, and instead:

- (always) requires distinct arguments: the script-file path followed by the arguments to pass to it.
- requires nothing but syntactic quoting with `"..."`, as needed, and treats the arguments as *literals*.

Therefore,

```sh
pwsh.exe -File .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B "-Path :"
```

*should* work - passing verbatim `-Path :` as the value to parameter `-B` - but *doesn't*, due to a ***bug*, still present as of PowerShell 7.2**.

- The problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #16432](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16432)

The problem is **the *combination* of an argument-initial `-` with a subsequent `:`**, which - **inappropriately - causes PowerShell to consider the argument a *named argument*, i.e. a *parameter name*-value combination**; that is, the `-Path` part is interpreted as targeting a parameter by that name (with whatever follows `:` as the parameter *value*), leaving parameter `-B` without an argument, which causes the error you saw.

There is **no workaround *per se***, only a suboptimal one that requires extra work on the part of the *script* too: you can start your argument with a *space* and later trim it inside `.\hello.ps1`:

```sh
pwsh.exe -File .\hello.ps1 -A 123 -B " -Path :"
```