# Why does powershell -c 'write-output "foo bar"' print its output on two lines?

Tags: powershell, console-output

When I invoke powershell with the `-c` command line parameter and a `write-output "foo bar"` command, the words are printed on separate lines:

```
PS> powershell -c 'write-output "foo bar"' 
foo
bar
```

When I execute the following line, it prints both words on the same line, which is what I expected for the above command as well:

```
powershell -c 'cmd /c echo foo bar'
foo bar
```

I don't understand what makes the word printed on separate lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136128/how-do-i-call-the-powershell-cli-robustly-with-respect-to-character-encoding-i search for `-Command`: _"but in the end PowerShell simply joins them together with spaces, after having stripped (unescaped) double quotes on Windows, before interpreting the resulting string as PowerShell code"_. You would just need to double down on the double quotes on your first example.

Answer (score 0):

As Santiago Squarzon said, this should work in Powershell

```
PS> powershell -c "write-output 'foo bar'"
foo bar
```