# How to convert the file path input spaces and backslash to unicode for using on a PowerShell command using "subprocess" module?

Tags: python, powershell, unicode, python-3.6, unicode-string

I have to use:

```
x=input()
subprocess.Popen(f'PowerShell -Executionpolicy byPass {x}\n')
```

To open an executable, but it does not allow me to use a path from the input of an variable that contains backslash or spaces that are not written in the following way:

- `'\\'` for backslashes.
- `'\u0020'` for spaces.

For `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Folder Name\executable.exe`
it should look like this:

```
'PowerShell -Executionpolicy byPass C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Folder\u0020Name\\executable.exe'
```

How could I replace all those spaces and backslashes on the variable for those unicode equivalents?
I need the user to be able just to copy and paste the executable's path.

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
x=input()
x=x.replace('\','\\')
x=x.replace(' ','\u0020')
```

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: For a path with a space character in it I would think you would need to enclose it in double quotes. i.e. `'PowerShell -Executionpolicy byPass "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Folder\u0020Name\\executable.exe"`

Comment: @martineau, enclosing a script file path containing spaces in double quotes when calling the Windows PowerShell CLI is _necessary_, but not _sufficient_, because - due to the CLI defaulting to `-Command` - those double quotes would be _stripped_ before being interpreted as PowerShell code; hence, preceding the script path with `-File` is required.

Answer (score 2):

- Do *not* try to use escaping on the *Python* side: `\`, when provided as part of a variable value needs no escaping, and neither do spaces.
- For *PowerShell*'s sake, however, file paths that contain spaces require *quoting*; when using PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe),  *double*-quoting (`"..."`) is needed.
- Additionally, you **use the `-File` CLI parameter explicitly** in order to execute a script *file*, because, by default, the `-Command` parameter is implied in *Windows PowerShell*, which interprets the following argument(s) as PowerShell source code, *after stripping unescaped `"` from them*, which causes script file paths *with spaces* to break.

  - Note: This applies to *Windows PowerShell*, but is **no longer strictly necessary in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), which now defaults to `-File`** rather than `-Command`.

Therefore:

```py
import subprocess

print('Enter the path of the .ps1 script to execute:')
x=input()
subprocess.Popen(f'PowerShell -Executionpolicy ByPass -File "{x}"').wait()
```

<sup>Note: To avoid unnecessary processing and to ensure a more predictable runtime environment, consider preceding `-File` with the `-NoProfile` switch, which suppresses loading of PowerShell's [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)</sup>

See also:

- [Guidance on when to use `-File` vs. `-Command`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375)
- [A comprehensive overview of PowerShell's CLI, in both editions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68136128/45375).

---

As [roeland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723966/45375) demonstrates, you may alternatively pass the arguments that make up the PowerShell CLI command line *individually* to `subprocess.Popen()`, as elements of an *array*.

While *Python* then conveniently takes care of double-quoting the elements *if necessary* on the command line it synthesizes behind the scenes (on Windows), the same rules discussed above apply here too: the script-file path argument must be qualified with `-File` in order for script paths *with spaces* to be invoked correctly:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['PowerShell', '-Executionpolicy', 'ByPass', '-File', x]).wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass arguments to a subprocess is to pass in the program with arguments as a list:

```py
    subprocess.Popen(['PowerShell', '-Executionpolicy', 'byPass', x])
```

This assumes `x` will only contain one single extra argument. If it potentially contains multiple arguments you’ll need to make a decision on how to split it, and how to handle paths with spaces.