# Powershell - The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

Hello everyone I have a problem with powershell if anyone could explain why I am receiving an error it would be greatly appreciated.

Trying to assign a simple string...

```
powershell $stringAssign = 'random string here'
```

= : The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Also tried putting it inside of a function, but it shows different error this time and a command I didn't even run...

```
powershell function DoStuff{$stringAssign = '3c68746d6c20786d6c6e733d22687474703a2f2f777777'}
```

At line:1 char:17
function DoStuff -encodedCommand JABzAHQAcgBpAG4AZwBBAHMAcwBpAGcAbgAg ...                 ~
Missing function body in function declaration.

Please anyone that can explain what is going on here and why an error is happening
when trying to assign a simple string, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying this from a PowerShell prompt?Why do your lines start with the word powershell?

Comment: Its only 1 line nothing more. I have tried from powershell prompt and as well cmd....both produce the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: You can put brackets around the code to make it a code block
`powershell {$stringAssign='random string here'}`

Comment: Putting brackets does work, but I am still perplexed why something so simple is giving off this error.

Comment: It's because when you're running this command from PowerShell the variables are being expanded before the command is run.  So for example, your first command is actually only `= 'random string here'` because $stringAssign gets expanded to its value of nothing

Comment: Run that same command without the word PowerShell in the front and it should work without any error

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, and as well explains why wrapping the script in brackets would work.

Comment: It works fine from cmd.

Answer (score 2):

To build on the helpful comments:

- You're calling the Windows PowerShell *CLI*, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), i.e. you're creating a child process to which you pass *command-line arguments*.
- **You must first satisfy the *calling* shell's syntax requirements to ensure that the arguments are passed as intended**, which **typically involves a *quoting* and /or *escaping***:

  - From `cmd.exe`, your command would work as-is (but do nothing useful), because none of the characters in `$stringAssign = 'random string here'` are subject to up-front interpretation *by `cmd.exe`*. However, it is safer to enclose the PowerShell command in `"..."`, because you then needn't worry about characters that `cmd.exe` *does* interpret itself if unquoted, such as `&`, `|`, and `>`:

    ```
    :: From cmd.exe      
    powershell "$stringAssign = 'random string here'; $stringAssign"
    ```

    - `;` is the statement separator, and `$stringAssign` simply outputs (echoes) the variable value, to demonstrate that the assignment worked.
    - If the command itself contains `"`, escape them as `\"` or - in edge cases - as `"^""` (sic; with `pwsh.exe`, the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI, use `""`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).
  - From PowerShell, your command fails for the reasons explained by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel):

    - `$stringAssign` is expanded *up front* in the *calling* session, and since no such variable exists yet, the command seen by the `powershell.exe` child process executes `= "random string here"`, which causes the error you saw.
    - The *immediate* fix is to enclose the command in [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), so that no up-front expansion is performed; embedding literal `'` inside `'...'` requires escaping them as `''`:

      ```
      powershell ' $stringAssign = ''random string here''; $stringAssign '
      ```

      - To include variable values from the *caller*'s scope, use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) with appropriate escaping with `` ` `` of the `$` in those variable reference that should *not* be expanded *up front*; e.g.:

        ```
        powershell "`$stringAssign = '$HOME'; $stringAssign; `$stringAssign"
        ```
    - Note that there is rarely a need to call the PowerShell CLI *from inside PowerShell*, because in-process execution is much faster than creating another PowerShell instance as a child process, but when you do, the best solution is to enclose the command in `{ ... }`, i.e. a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), but note that this works *only* from PowerShell.

      ```
      # Works from PowerShell only.
      powershell { $stringAssign = 'random string here'; $stringAssign }
      ```

      - To include variable values from the *caller*'s scope, you must pass them *as arguments*, which in the simplest case you can access via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args):

        ```
        # Works from PowerShell only.
        powershell { $stringAssign = $args[0]; $stringAssign } -args $HOME
        ```

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's CLI, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68136128/45375).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message in different code, which leads me to this page.

In my case I was using C3 syntax in if

```
if($foo == $false)
```

instead of Powershell syntax

```
if($foo -eq $false)
```