# Capturing output from Powershell command and saving it in a variable

Tags: python, dataframe, powershell, subprocess

I keep trying to run this piece of code but everytime I print, it seems to net me nothing in regards to what I see with my output.

```
p = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", "C://Users//xxxxx//Documents//betterNetstatOut.ps1"], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

output = p.stdout
print(output)
```

My PowerShell command is a very basic println at this point:

```
Write-Output 'Hello world'
```

but running print on my out seems to return an empty string. I also tried running subprocess.Popen() and subprocess.call() and they all seem to return an empty string instead of 'Hello World'. Eventually, I would like to parse many lines and move them to a dataframe but I am stuck on this one line first.

Comment: try with `["powershell.exe", "-File", "path//to//file"]...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PowerShell command likely produced only *stderr* output, which is why you saw no output given that you only printed `p.stdout` - also printing `p.stderr` would surface any stderr output (which typically contains error messages).

Assuming your script file path is correct, the likeliest explanation for receiving only stderr output is that your effective PowerShell [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) prevents execution of scripts (`.ps1` files), which you can bypass with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` in a call to the Windows PowerShell CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe).

Additionally:

- There's no need for *double* slashes (`//`) in your script path; while it still works, `/` is sufficient.
- It's better to use the `-File` parameter rather than `-Command` (which is implied) for invoking scripts via the PowerShell CLI - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for more information.
- For a predictably execution environment and to avoid unnecessary overhead from loading [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), using `-NoProfile` is advisable.
- You don't need `shell=True`, which, due to calling via `cmd.exe`, only slows your command down.

To put it all together:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run(
     ["powershell.exe", 
      "-NoProfile", 
      "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", 
      "-File", "C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/betterNetstatOut.ps1"], 
     capture_output=True, text=True
    )

print('--- stdout --')
print(p.stdout)
print('--- stderr --')
print(p.stderr)
```

Comment: Follow-up question: Is there a way to handle the PowerShell command without looking for a .ps1 file? Just run 'netstat -a' directly from the subprocess.run() function?

Comment: @ZarifRahman, use `-Command` instead of `-File`, and pass `'netstat -a'` to it. If you need a comprehensive overview of the PowerShell CLI, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136129/45375). That said, if _all_ you need is a call to `netstat`, you don't need PowerShell at all - just use `'netstat.exe'` instead of `"powershell.exe"` and `'-a'` as its argument.

Comment: Thank you for the example! But 'netstat -a' is just an example I wanted to run through.

Comment: @ZarifRahman, understood. Then use the `-Command` approach.

Comment: I am running this piece of code great within my terminal but running it as an executable causes the PowerShell window to keep opening and closing. I am using PyInstaller to create my exe and was wondering if there was a way to suppress the powershell window from showing up?

Comment: I see that you've created a follow-up question about launching PowerShell _invisibly_ at https://stackoverflow.com/q/73735991/45375

Comment: Yup! Haha, from my research, this issue seemed a little bit more complicated than in this original question. Didn't think this would be a bigger deal when posting this comment but slowly realized what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File", "C://Users//xxxxx//Documents//betterNetstatOut.ps1"], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
print(p.stdout)
```

Comment: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` is a good pointer, but Is the _nesting_ of `powershell.exe` calls in your code a typo?