# Unexpected token '}' when passing string to PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, quoting

I have a script that accepts two strings, each are delimited by `'|-|'`. The second string can contain any character other than `'`.

To call the script I do:

```
PowerShell .\script.ps1 -arg1 'Hello|-|World' -arg2 'random|-|dwua0928]43d}'
```

It raises an error on the character `}`. How can I resolve this?

Edit:
It also has an issue with the `-` from the delimiters and raises the same error:

```
At line:1 char:54
+ .\Script.ps1 -arg2 <redacted>|-|<redacted> ...    
+                                ~
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:53
+ .\Script.ps1 -arg1 <redacted>|-|<redacted> ...    
+                               ~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
```

It does that at every instance of `|-|`. It does it with the brackets if I change the delimiter to `/-/`:

```
At line:1 char:168
+ ... <redacted>/-/<redacted>!OW}:Lj<redacted> ...
+                               ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:181
+ ... /-/<redacted>cO0}e]k<redacted> ...
+                     ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
```

The beginning of the script is this:

```
Param
(
    [switch] $enable,
    [string] $arg1,
    [string] $arg2
)
```

Comment: How can we tell you what's wrong with the script if you don't show the script?

Comment: Please share the complete error message (formatted as code as well, please)

Comment: Do you run this command line from a PowerShell console or from a CMD? If it is the latter one use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: @Olaf: Good point in general, but with `'...'` quoting the command would have broken _differently_ from `cmd.exe`, and, conversely, `"..."` quoting  (without escaping of the `"` chars.) wouldn't help, and would result in the errors shown in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There's generally *no* need to call the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+)  from *inside* PowerShell.

  - Assuming you're running *Windows PowerShell* (or, to generalize, the *same edition* of PowerShell), you can invoke your script *directly*:

    ```
    .\script.ps1 -arg1 'Hello|-|World' -arg2 'random|-|dwua0928]43d}'
    ```
- If you still want to call the CLI - which is *expensive*, because it involves creating a *child* process, and also results in a loss of *type fidelity* - use a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), but note that this works only from *inside* PowerShell (though it works across both PowerShell editions, i.e., you can call `pwsh.exe` from Windows PowerShell, and `powershell.exe` from PowerShell (Core) 7+)

  ```
  powershell { .\script.ps1 -arg1 'Hello|-|World' -arg2 'random|-|dwua0928]43d}' }
  ```
- If you were to call from *outside* PowerShell, it is best to use the `-File` CLI parameter rather than the (implied in Windows PowerShell) `-Command` parameter:

  ```
  powershell -File .\script.ps1 -arg1 "Hello|-|World" -arg2 "random|-|dwua0928]43d}"
  ```

  - While this works from inside PowerShell too, the disadvantage compared to the `{ ... }` approach is that the output is only ever *text*, whereas the `{ ... }` approach is - within limits - capable of preserving the original data types - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for more information.
  - In order to make a `-Command`-based command line work, enclose the PowerShell code in `"..."` *as a whole*, in which case the embedded `'...'` strings *are* passed as such:

    ```
    powershell -Command ".\script.ps1 -arg1 'Hello|-|World\' -arg2 'random|-|dwua0928]43d}'"
    ```

For a comprehensive overview of the PowerShell CLI, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68136128/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- You called `powershell.exe` with neither `-File` (`-f`) nor `-Command` (`-c`), which defaults to `-Command` (note that, by contrast, `pwsh`, the PowerShell (Core) 7+ CLI, defaults to `-File`).
- When `-Command` is used, PowerShell's command-line processing first strips all subsequent arguments of any syntactic (i.e., unescaped) `"` characters, namely from `"..."`-enclosed arguments, joins the resulting tokens with spaces, and *then* interprets the resulting string *as PowerShell code*.
- In your case, the fact that you used `'...'` quoting around the arguments is irrelevant:

  - PowerShell invariably translates the original quoting into `"..."` quoting when calling *external programs* (as they can only be expected to `"..."` quoting, not also `'...'` quoting)
  - However, it only uses `"..."` quoting *if needed*, which is solely based on whether the argument at hand *contains spaces*.

Neither of your arguments, verbatim `Hello|-|World` and `random|-|dwua0928]43d}`, contained spaces, so they were placed *as-is* on the command line for `powershell.exe` (though note that even if they *did* contain spaces and had been enclosed in `"..."` as a result, PowerShell's command-line processing would have stripped the `"` chars.)

The net result was that the `powershell.exe` child process tried to execute the following PowerShell code, which predictably breaks with the errors shown in your question:

```
# !! Note the absence of quoting around the -arg1 and -arg2 values.
.\script.ps1 -arg1 Hello|-|World -arg2 random|-|dwua0928]43d}
```

You can easily provoke the error you saw as follows from a PowerShell session:

```
# -> Error "Missing expression after unary operator '-'."
Write-Output Hello|-|World
```

Comment: As usual - perfectly explained. I always feel that I don't know nothing yet when I read your explanations. ;-)

Comment: Explained amazingly, thank you so much for your help, and thanks @Olaf

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Olaf; thank you for the nice feedback.

Comment: My pleasure, @Thermohalia; I'm glad the answer helped.