# Why are there two pairs of quotes for PowerShell arguments?

Tags: c#, powershell, window, quotes

I was building a Windows Service that needs to periodically execute PowerShell scripts (`*.ps1 -Option Value` etc) via C#'s `Process` and I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30846513/235671) about how to do this, but the example there uses two pairs of quotes (first double `"` then single `'`) for the `Arguments` which is quite confusing:

```cs
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"&'"+strCmdText+"'\"";
```

Are they both really necessary and if yes then why?

Comment: You can execute Powershell directly from C#, you don't have to go out to `powershell.exe` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments

Comment: @Charlieface I know, thx :) Unfortunately the launcher (Windows Service) cannot be updated quickly so I've got to deal with it in the _classical_ way for now.

Comment: The generous bounty award is much appreciated, @t3chb0t.

Comment: @mklement0 it's lots of details for such a _simple_ one sentence question, but now I feel like I little by little know what I'm actually doing there and not just copy/pasting stuff ;-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To offer a more PowerShell-focused answer:

> the example there uses two pairs of quotes (first double `"` then single `'`) for the Arguments (...) Are they both really necessary and if yes then why?

- The quoting requirements depend on whether the `-File` or the `-Command` parameter of the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) is used.

  - In the absence of either parameter, `powershell.exe` assumes `-Command`, `pwsh.exe` assumes `-File`.
  - `-Command` allows you to pass arbitrary PowerShell commands, with the code optionally spread across multiple arguments.

    - *Unescaped* `"` characters are *stripped during the initial command-line parsing*, but `'` characters are passed through as-is.
    - Preserving `"` *as part of the PowerShell code to execute* require escaping them as `\"` (sic; even though PowerShell-*internally* `` `" `` must be used).
  - `-File` expects the path of a *script file* (`*.ps1`) to execute, with any *additional* arguments being passed as literal values to that script.

    - Only `"` quoting can be used with *syntactic* function - any `'` characters are used *verbatim*.
- Fundamentally - with both `-File` and `-Command` - a script-file path only needs quoting if it contains *metacharacters*, notably *spaces*.
- When quoting *is* needed, the approaches differ depending on `-Command` vs. `-File`:
- `-File`:

  - Use embedded `"..."` quoting around the file path (and around any pass-through arguments that need quoting) - escaped as `""...""` for the sake of embedding in the C# verbatim string:

    ```
    var scriptPath = @"C:\path with spaces\script.ps1";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"-File ""{scriptPath}""";
    ```
- `-Command`:

  - While embedded `'...'` quoting, as in the question, *could* be used, doing so isn't *fully robust*, unless extra action is taken: `'` is a legal character in file names, so a path containing `'` would break the command (which could be avoided with extra effort; see the edge case below).
  - Using embedded `"..."` quoting avoids this problem, given that `"` isn't valid in file names (at least on Windows). For the reasons stated above, this requires `\`-escaping the `"` characters (spaces added for readability):

    ```
     var scriptPath = @"C:\path with spaces\script.ps1";
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = $@" -Command "" & \""{scriptPath}\"" "" ";
    ```
  - Note:

    - If the *only* operation you're performing is calling a *script* with *literal* arguments, there is *no* reason to use `-Command` - use `-File` instead.
    - It is a fundamental syntax requirement in PowerShell (which does't apply to `-File`) that a *quoted* command must be called via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).
    - The code to execute is passed as a *single* argument, enclosed in `"..."` to `-Command`. This isn't strictly necessary in an invocation that doesn't involve a *shell*, but *avoids whitespace normalization* that would result from PowerShell "stitching" multiple arguments back together to form the code to execute.
    - There's a - largely hypothetical - edge case (which does *not* affect the `-File` parameter): If you had file paths that contain verbatim tokens such as `$foo`, they would be subject to - unwanted - string interpolation by PowerShell; in that case, embedded `'...'` quoting must be used instead, but with any *embedded* `'` chars. escaped as `''`:

      ```
      var scriptPath = @"C:\path with spaces\script.ps1";
      process.StartInfo.Arguments = $@" -Command "" & '{scriptPath.Replace("'", "''")}' "" ";
      ```

Answer (score 1):

The use of multiple pairs of quotes in the `Arguments` property when executing a PowerShell script via C#'s `Process` is not necessary in most cases. It seems like the code snippet you provided might be overly complex or contain unnecessary quotes.

In general, when setting the `Arguments` property for a PowerShell script in C#, you typically only need to provide the path to the script file itself. For example:

```cs
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "path/to/script.ps1";
```

This assumes that you have set the `FileName` property of the `ProcessStartInfo` object to the path of the PowerShell executable (`powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe` depending on your system).

However, there might be certain cases where you need to pass additional arguments or deal with spaces or special characters in the script path. In such situations, you may need to enclose the path in double quotes. For example:

```cs
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"path/to/script with spaces.ps1\"";
```

In this case, the double quotes are used to ensure that the entire path is treated as a single argument.

Based on the code snippet you provided (`\"&'"+strCmdText+"'\"`), it seems like you are trying to pass a command or script text as an argument rather than a script file path. However, the specific usage of double and single quotes in that snippet appears to be unnecessary and could potentially lead to syntax errors.

To provide a more accurate answer, it would be helpful if you could provide the context or specific requirements for executing the PowerShell script so that I can assist you further.

Comment: oh, I get it! I also added more details to the setup. It's a Windows Service that periodically runs `*.ps1` scripts.